# How do I properly handle a memory warning in the UIPickerViewController for my UIImageView with an image in it?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

So I have a `UIImageView` on a view. The view also has a button on it to pop a `UIPickerViewController` or camera controls. When someone selects an image, it sets the `myImageView.image` property and displays the image in my view. No saving of the image is done... it's just a display of what you've chosen.

Sometimes, when I'm in `UIPickerViewController`, I get a memory warning. Because the picker is open, all of the other non-visble views, including my `UIImageView`, get released and viewDidLoad gets called again when the picker closes. This is as expected. But in the process I lose the image I was displaying as the image reverts back to it's original "choose an image" image placeholder.

But how do I load the image that was in the `UIImageView` BEFORE the memory warning back into the `UIImageView`? Since it was in memory, it's now lost. And I don't know it's location because the user picked it from the picker and I just took it straight from there with this:

```
itemImageView.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
```

Any ideas on how to recover that lost image? Or if I should save it in some variable or to the device to use again in case of a memory warning??

Comment: I thing you can just save that image to app document directory and use it whenever you need. It also cleans the code and release tension as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to retain a reference to the image as well as showing it in the UIImageView. e.g. save it in a property called `selectedImage`:

.h:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage* selectedImage;
```

Image picker delegate:

```
self.selectedImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
itemImageView.image = selectedImage;
```

Then when `itemImageView` is unloaded (along with the rest of the view) due to low memory, you will still have the image retained. In `viewDidLoad`, check to see if you have an image that you should show:

```
if (selectedImage != nil)
    itemImageView.image = selectedImage;
```

Make sure you release `selectedImage` when it's appropriate to do so for your app - e.g. when the user progresses beyond this screen, or when they cancel selecting this image, or when you save it out to the file system etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it would be better if you have a variable for the image and retaining the image.